# How could I use a function thats inside a for loop in python

Tags: python

I have a function that prints out the students that has passed an exam. But if I do the function like this:

```
csv_dict_reader = csv.reader(
    read_obj,
    delimiter=";",
)
next(csv_dict_reader)
for row in csv_dict_reader:

    if row[11]:
        #     allPassedStudents.append(row[0])
        passedDate = datetime.strptime(row[11], "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")

    if passedDate:

        if passedDate < end_date:
            fastStudent.append(row[0])
            print(fastStudent)
```

I get a print like this:`

```
['1']
['1', '2']
['1', '2', '3']
['1', '2', '3', '41']
['1', '2', '3', '41', '49']
```

these numbers are studentnumbers!
How could I get it so it shows everystudent just once. student is row[0] in my function and row[11] is the date they passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this :

```py
csv_dict_reader = csv.reader(read_obj, delimiter=';',)
    next(csv_dict_reader)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
        
        if row[11]:
        #     allPassedStudents.append(row[0])
            passedDate = datetime.strptime(row[11], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M') 
    
        if passedDate:

            if passedDate < end_date:
                fastStudent.append(row[0])
    print(fastStudent)
```

I don't have your dataset to test it. But now it should work I guess.

Comment: ohh wow yeahh exactly like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- only do `print(fastStudent)` *after* the loop (since `fastStudent` is the list you're gathering those ids into), or
- do `print(row[0])` in the loop (so you only print the ID you just appended).